# How do I test a calling/meeting bot locally in MS Teams?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have used this [yeoman generator](https://github.com/pnp/generator-teams) to generate an app and a bot.

I have registered the bot with the [bot framework](https://dev.botframework.com/) and added the MS teams channel and specified it should be a calling bot. I have also updated my app registration in azure and assigned it the Microsoft Graph permissions as outlined in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/registering-calling-bot) document.

I have not modified the bot at all, all I have is what is generated from the generator. When I deploy my bot in MS teams (just a developer license) I can have a conversation with the bot and get responses but how do I test the calling/meeting functionality?

Ideally what I want, is a meeting bot that will listen for meetings starting, ending and people joining. I believe this is possible but I don't know how to test it locally.

Edit - including sample manifest.json produced by generator:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-app-schema/preview/DevPreview/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "devPreview",
  "id": "{{APPLICATION_ID}}",
  "version": "{{VERSION}}",
  "packageName": "{{PACKAGE_NAME}}",
  "developer": {
    "name": "sample",
    "websiteUrl": "https://{{HOSTNAME}}",
    "privacyUrl": "https://{{HOSTNAME}}/privacy.html",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://{{HOSTNAME}}/tou.html"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "calling-bot-test",
    "full": "calling-bot-test"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "TODO: add short description here",
    "full": "TODO: add full description here"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "icon-outline.png",
    "color": "icon-color.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#D85028",
  "configurableTabs": [
    {
      "configurationUrl": "https://{{HOSTNAME}}/fstCallingBotTab/config.html?name={loginHint}&tenant={tid}&group={groupId}&theme={theme}",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
      "scopes": [
        "team",
        "groupchat"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "staticTabs": [],
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "{{MICROSOFT_APP_ID}}",
      "needsChannelSelector": true,
      "isNotificationOnly": false,
      "scopes": [
        "team",
        "personal",
        "groupchat"
      ],
      "commandLists": [
        {
          "scopes": [
            "team",
            "personal"
          ],
          "commands": [
            {
              "title": "Help",
              "description": "Shows help information"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "supportsCalling": true,
      "supportsVideo": true
    }
  ],
  "connectors": [],
  "composeExtensions": [],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "{{HOSTNAME}}"
  ]
}
```

Comment: As suggested by @Shane Could you please test your bot using ngrok also Just for conformation did you enable developer preview option? If no could you please test your bot in developer preview mode? Could you please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/registering-calling-bot) for more info?

Comment: Yes, when I run the generator I made sure I selected devPreview for the question 
"Which manifest version would you like to use?"

Comment: You can use the latest version. Could you please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema) for more info?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) which is the same application that [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/debug) recommends as well.  It's simple and free.  The only reason you would need the paid version of ngrok is if you need [real time media](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/real-time-media-concepts) support which is not likely for most people.

UPDATE:
You asked specifically about testing the "meeting component"... I assume you mean call bot support for meetings?

This is not something you can "test" without code changes.

Call bots support:

- Inbound 1 to 1 calls
- Outbound 1 to 1 calls
- Outbound multi-party calls

Ready the [overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/calls-meetings-bots-overview) section careful and it goes over all of this.

You test inbound 1 to 1 calls by setting up your bot manifest to say it support [calling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/registering-calling-bot).  When the bot app is installed onto a teams client you should see a call button on the bot page that you can "call" the bot with.  That is how you do a inbound 1 to 1 call.

To test outbound 1 to 1 calls / multi-party calls, your bot code need to generate a outbound call based on some sort of trigger you make up.

Maybe it's better if you go through the [sample applications](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples) and get them up and running and see how they work. If you play with them and understand what they are doing then that will answer your "how to" questions.

Comment: I run the server via the command gulp ngrok-serve. This command is created as part of yeoman generator I use. I know it is working because I can send and receive conversational text messages. I just don't know how to test the meetings component

Comment: Updated my answer with what I hope helps you.

Comment: Thanks @Shane Powell. I do mean call bot support for meetings. I have been the through that Registering a calling bot for Microsoft Teams page and I thought I had set it up correctly but i can't see the "call" button on my bot. I guess I have set something up incorrectly. I will go back through it step by step and see what I have done wrong. 

I am trying to write my bot in JavaScript as that is what I know. I have tried going through those sample apps but found it hard understand because they are in .NET. I will try and go through them again and see what I can find

Comment: There is no "call bot support for meetings" per say...   To a call bot a "meeting" call is no different to a multi-party call.  The only difference is some extra meta-data against the call about the meeting.   So where you see "multi-party call" in the doc's you can replace with "meeting" if you like.

Comment: The "Call" button is a manifest setup for the bot that you install into the teams client to see the "Bot" tab.  In that bot tab you should see a call button.   It have nothing to do with your bot app that runs on your machine, but the "app" setup install onto your teams client that tells the teams client what your bot can accept (messages, calls, etc).

Comment: OK, 

As mentioned above I am using the yeoman generator "generator teams" to produce my app with a calling bot. As part of this process it produces a manifest.json file (I have now edited my original question to add the sample manifest.json).

I believe you're saying that this manifest controls the display of the call button. I think the manifest file above will support calling but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: I've never used the "yeoman generator" so I don't know what that does.  I'm talking about the manifest created by App Studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/app-studio-overview

Comment: No problems.Thanks for your help. The generator produces a zip folder container the  manifest.json file (see above) file and png. I then deploy this zip file into teams using the Upload Custom App option. Maybe there is a problem with the generator and I should do it manually using App Studio